# R Reticulate--Use Python Module with Tidyverse Mutate

Tags: python, r, reticulate, mutate

I'd like to use the tiktoken python module with the R tidyverse mutate function. The module works fine on its own but throws an error when used in a tidyverse mutate statement. The error is:

Error in `cnd_type()`:
! `cnd` is not a condition object

Here's a reproducible example:

```
library(reticulate)
tiktoken <- import("tiktoken")
encoding <- tiktoken$encoding_for_model("gpt-4")

#This works fine
prompt <- "John Lennon"
length(encoding$encode(prompt))

#Create df
beatles <- data.frame(name=c("John Lennon", "Paul McCartney",
                             "George Harrison", "Ringo Starr"),
instrument=c("Guitar", "Bass", "Guitar", "Drums"))

#run tiktoken on each cell of the name column
#this produces the error
beatles %>% 
  mutate(n_tokens = length(encoding$encode(name)))
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I got it to work by using [sapply](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.2/topics/lapply) to apply the function to each element of the vector.

```r
beatles %>% 
  mutate(n_tokens = sapply(name, function (x) length(encoding$encode(x))))
```

You can also make this faster using encode_batch():

```r
beatles %>% 
  mutate(n_tokens = sapply(encoding$encode_batch(name), function (x) length(x)))
```

Comment: Turns out each approach takes about the same time.  The data file has 500K lines of text (transcribed conversations).  The sapply approach took 51.5 seconds and the dplyr/rowwise one 52.9 seconds.

Comment: @BBJonz Since you're looking for speed, I saw in the documentation that there is an encode_batch() function in tiktoken, which should avoid some of the calls back and forth between R and Python. I found that it was roughly 2x faster (5s vs 9s) on a dataset of Jane Austen books.

Comment: Thanks, Nick.  That reduced processing time to 15.1 seconds.

Answer (score 1):

You could also try a tidyverse approach with `rowwise()`

```
beatles %>% 
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(n_tokens = length(encoding$encode(name)))
```

Comment: Much thanks to you and Nick!  Both solutions work just fine.  For fun I'd like to benchmark each on my data (500k lines of text).  Will report back.